# How to push data with Mongoose to a nested array in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I'm trying to push data to a nested array in mongodb. I'm using mongoose as well.

This is just mock code to see if i can get it working:

User model:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const CoinSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  coinID: { type: String },
});
const CoinsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  coin: [CoinSchema],
});

const WatchlistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  watchlistName: { type: String },
  coins: [CoinsSchema],
});

const NameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: { type: String },
  lastName: { type: String },
  username: { type: String },
});

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: [NameSchema],
  watchlists: [WatchlistSchema],
  test: String,
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

export default User;
```

route:

```
fastify.put("/:id", async (request, reply) => {
    try {
      const { id } = request.params;
      const newCoin = request.body;
      const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
        $push: { "watchlists[0].coins[0].coin": newCoin },
      });
      await updatedUser.save();
      // console.dir(updatedUser, { depth: null });
      reply.status(201).send(updatedUser);
    } catch (error) {
      reply.status(500).send("could not add to list");
    }
  });
```

**request.body // "coinID": "test"**

I've tried a lot of different ways to push this data but still no luck. I still get 201 status codes in my terminal which indicates something has been pushed to the DB, but when I check nothing new is there.

Whats the correct way to target nested arrays and push data to them?

Comment: Can you check if the arrays you are trying to push to have been initialized in MongoDB in the first place? If not, then you won't be able to push to them

Comment: The `coin` array exists already yes, and there's already a coin in there from when i created the user, now id like to add more objects to that array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not perfect but you could get the user document, update the user's watchlist, and then save the updated watchlist like so:

```
fastify.put("/:id", async (request, reply) => {
    try {
        const { id } = request.params;
        const newCoin = request.body;
        
        // get the user
        let user = await User.findById(id);

        // push the new coin to the User's watchlist
        user.watchlists[0].coins[0].coin.push(newCoin);

        //update the user document
        const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id },
            {
                watchlists: user.watchlists,
            }, 
            { 
                new: true, 
                useFindAndModify: false 
            }
        );
        
        reply.status(201).send(updatedUser);
    } catch (error) {
        reply.status(500).send("could not add to list");
    }
  });
```